# Is it possible to dodge a Tower shot after it has locked onto you and fired?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there anyway to dodge a Tower shot after it has already been fired at you? I find myself Tower-Diving to chase an enemy down, only to get sniped at the last second by a heavy bullet that had been chasing me. Is there a way to dodge one after it has been fired after me?

I would prefer answers that can apply to many/all champions.

Comment: Do you really want to dodge the turret shot, or just avoid the damage. this is a tiny difference.

Comment: Dodge the shot, I know many chars can block/avoid the damage while still getting hit.

Comment: well technicly you will still get hit by the turret if its projectile is already flying even when using Zhonya's. You just don't take any damage. or am I wrong?

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Good way to test this theory.  Pick a champion that has a quick instant dash and take flash.  (Lissandra?)  Get tower aggro then get away as far as possible and activate Zhonya's.  The bullet travels slow so if you can get far enough away for Zhonya's stasis to end it should then still do damage.  (You could likely time this using TP as well.  Let a minion die mid TP while the bullet fires at you.)

Comment: @dphil you won't be able to get so far away, that the zhonyas ends before the turret shot arrives

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW I wasn't sure if you could get that far away using mobility + flash.  My TP method though would work for sure, it would just be far harder to do it at the exact right time.

Comment: @dphil tp channels for too long (3.5secs)

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW That's what makes it so hard.  You need to time it with a minion dying.  You don't let the tower instant aggro you.  You would start tping while it finishes off one of your minions.  You need it to switch aggro to you right before you finish TPing.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHH now i get it.... well that might be possible :-) i won't try it tho :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to "dodge" a Tower shot after it has been fired is to become untargetable. Several champions have this capability, but every champion can become untargetable through the use of Zhonya's Hourglass. However, to survive a tower with Zhonya's, one of several things must happen:

1. *Get out of the tower's natural range before using Zhonya's* - The thing about Zhonya's is that it freezes you in place. It does you very little good if you use it right under the tower as the tower will just shoot at you again as soon as you unfreeze. Get out of range with a dash, Flash, or any other movement ability and pop Zhonya's.
2. *Activate Zhonya's with nearby minions* - Zhonya's will remove you from the targeting list, essentially resetting the tower's focus. If done while in the middle of a minion wave or right before one arrives, you can get the tower to focus back on a minion while you unfreeze and stroll to safety.
3. *Stall for time* - If you have an allied champion with an emergency save ability (Soraka, Zilean, Shen, etc.), you can stall for time with Zhonya's and then try to get that champion's attention before the effect wears off. This can be especially useful if the champion is just waiting on a cooldown to come back up before they can save.

Be aware that if you damage an enemy champion as you come out of the Zhonya's Hourglass effect, the tower *will* target you again (unless you're out of range due to option #1). Be careful when tower diving as a champion with damage-over-time abilities like Malzahar.

While I've mostly talked about Zhonya's with this answer, this applies to *all* abilities that render you untargetable (Fizz, Vladimir, Bard, etc.)

Comment: There's also the option of dropping aggro with zhonya. If teammates are nearby and they damage an opponent they'll grab aggro and you'll be safe.

Comment: shaco can dodge with his ultimate

Comment: I would also list spells that make a champion invulnerable. It not dodging, but you can avoid the damage. which was the initial intention.

Comment: Yi can also dodge with his Q

Comment: There is an item that temporarily disables a turret ([Ohmwrecker](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ohmwrecker)).  I am not sure if using it on the turret while the shot is in the air would instantly stop that shot, or prevent the damage, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is one way that works for every champion and doesn't need any items, **BUT** it requires the tower to be low hp;

If the tower gets destroyed while the projectile is in the air, for some reason, you don't take any damage from it. I've been saved couple of times because of this (and lost some kills). It doesn't help you much, but you really shouldn't dive if you're that afraid of getting shot by the tower.

And of course you can flash away if you're quick. The towers firing system works in really weird way (*imo*), sometimes when you enter the range, it takes a small amount of time until the tower shoots at you and sometimes it shots you instantly when entering the range.

Answer (score 0):

If a Tower shot has already been fired the only way to 'dodge' the shot is to become untargetable (with skills such as Fizz's Playful/Trickster, Kalista's Fate's Call) or for the tower in question to be destroyed (doing so will make it appear that the tower shot hit you but will deal no damage).

I'm not too sure how Bard's Ultimate/Ohmwrecker will affect this. Obviously it stops the tower from firing all together but I don't know if it will cause any shots fired to miss as well. Successive shots will not however deal increased damage if the tower has been disabled and will start again dealing base damage and wracking up (as towers deal more damage the more shots you have already taken).

Apart from that the only other possibility I can think of (however gimmicky) is to either teleport/recall while taking turret agro and the shot will fly across the map (similar to Nunu's Iceblast). I don't know if you will evade the shot or if it will simply follow you across the map, but you will have healed up in base so it will hardly matter.